# Can I create a server php variable?

Tags: php

I want to have my own variable that would be (most likely an array) storing what my php application is up to right now.

The application can trigger few processes that are in background (like downloading files) and I want to have a list what is being currently processed.

For example

- if php calls exec() that will be downloading for 15mins
- and then another download starts
- and another download starts

then if I access my application I want to be able to see that `3 downloads` are in process. If none of them finished yet.

Can do that? Only in memory, not storing anything on the disk?

I thought that the solution would be a some kind of server variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean with "storing what my php application is up to right now"? Either nothing if there are no requests or see the access log of your webserver.

Comment: Updated my question - see For example.

Comment: Well there is nothing like a serverside variable in PHP. Multiple requests will be handled by multiple processes. The only way to achieve something like that is by storing it in a db or a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone for [shared memory](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php)?

Obviously you would have to have some sort of daemon, but you could use the inbuilt semaphore functions to easily have contact between each of the scripts. You need to be careful though because sometimes if you're not closing the memory block properly, you could risk ending up with no blocks left.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't have knowledge of previous processes. As soon has a php process is finished everything it knows about itself goes with it.

I can think of two options. Write knowledge about spawned processes to a file or database and use it to sync all your php request, (store the PID of each spawned process)

Or

Create an Daemon. The people behind PHP have worked hard to clean up PHP memory handling and such to make this more feasible. Take a look at their PEAR package -  http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon

Off the top of my head, a quick architecture would compose of 3 peices

Part A) The web app that will take in request for downloads, and report back the progress of all request

Part B) You daemon, which accepts requests for downloads, spawns process, and will report back status of all spawned reqeust

Part C) The spawn request that will perform the download you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store your own variables in $_SERVER. The best method would be to store your data in a database where and query/update it as required.